# How does SVN work?

Tags: svn, repository, dropbox

I have configured `SVN` on my `Dropbox` folder.
Inside my dropbox I have a folder named `DropboxSvnRepository` and another folder under other location (not inside Dropbox) named `DropboxSvnClient` and inside this folder I have 3 folders:

1. branches
2. tags
3. trunk

Right click on `DropboxSvnClient` folder open menu:

1. SVN update
2. SVN commit

My questions:

1. Where do I need to store my projects that I want to save inside my Dropbox folder (DropboxSvnRepository)?
2. If I want to open a new solution - where do I need to open it before saving it to my Dropbox?
3. What happens if I delete my local solution?
4. What does SVN update and SVN commit do?

Comment: In contrast to much free software SVN is very well documented.  See, for example, http://subversion.apache.org/docs/ Once you've read the documentation come back and ask any remaining questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to read the SVN manual (aka the SVN redbook).  Once you have a handle on how to use SVN, the only items which will stand in your way are the drop-box additions, which are simple enough if you understand the SVN tool itself.

Please google for "svn redbook" and then read the first few chapters.  After two or three chapters, you probably have all you need to be an effective user of SVN.  Without it, attempting to find the same amount of information one question at a time is like trying to learn how to drive a car, one accident at a time.